# How can I use tensorflow read/write files from hdfs?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use tensorflow to write and read files from hdfs.I used 'pip install ten……' to install tensorflow.And when I read file from hdfs,it's does work,just stop at there and no error reply.
Do I need to install tensorflow by ./configure and than bazel build?Is it must install like this way it can support hdfs?

here is my code write file to local file system:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph,config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./mnist_logs2/', graph_def=sess.graph_def)
    for i in range(2000000):
        batch=mnist.train.next_batch(10000)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0],y_:batch[1],keep_prob:0.8})

        if i%100==0:
            acc_test=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_:mnist.test.labels,keep_prob:1.0})
            print("step %d,test accuracy %g"%(i,acc_test))
            if acc_test>0.993:
                break

    saver_path=saver.save(sess,'/home/test/mnist/model.ckpt')

    print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_:mnist.test.labels,keep_prob:1.0}))
```

here is my code I write file to hdfs,only change the path:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph,config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('hdfs://user/mlp/zpc/mnist_logs2/', graph_def=sess.graph_def)
    for i in range(2000000):
        batch=mnist.train.next_batch(10000)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0],y_:batch[1],keep_prob:0.8})

        if i%100==0:
            acc_test=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_:mnist.test.labels,keep_prob:1.0})
            print("step %d,test accuracy %g"%(i,acc_test))
            if acc_test>0.993:
                break

    saver_path=saver.save(sess,'hdfs://user/mlp/zpc/mnist_logs2/model.ckpt')

    print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y_:mnist.test.labels,keep_prob:1.0}))
```

when I run the code which write to hdfs, I run like below:

```
CLASSPATH=$($HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath --glob) python mnist_linux.py
```

Comment: can you provide a minimalistic sample code that does read from file but with a single line change it uses hdfs and files?

Comment: I already update some code to the question,please help check.But I want to know if I install tensorflow use pip install tensorflow , is it support hdfs?

Comment: I don't see the code that tries to read from hdfs and fails.  Am I missing something?

Comment: 'summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('hdfs://user/mlp/zpc/mnist_logs2/', graph_def=sess.graph_def)',and 'saver_path=saver.save(sess,'hdfs://user/mlp/zpc/mnist_logs2/model.ckpt')'